# run time analysis of a for loop

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I am trying to prepare for a test comping up on run-time analysis.  I have been hit with a for loop that is throwing me a bit.  I am hoping someone can help me.

the loop is

```
for(j=1; j< n; j=j*2)
```

J is increasing at an increasing rate so it will be less than n/2  however I am having trouble concluding what exactly it will be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) In particular, see the section "While-Loops" in [this answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/23594/9550). The example loop there is essentially identical to this one, except that the loop in this question "counts up", whereas that one counts down.

Comment: That is probably a way over complicated answer.  Also I don't fully follow it.  Nor does it seem to give the answer i was looking for.  I was hoping for something like a log n and an explanation why.  That seems to be more of logic for a for loop and not the run time specifically for j=j*2 and if it is then I am sorry I just didn't follow the math myself

Comment: Welcome to the site! You're right in observing that our "reference questions" aren't as immediately helpful as they could be. Because they are intended to be useful for a wide range of questions about a topic, they necessarily have a lot of detail that might actually obscure the answer a visitor needs. This is a decision that was made a while ago and while some of us aren't happy about it, it's just what we have to deal with. If you stick around here you'll find that you might have a better chance of getting useful help if you ask sharply defined and limited questions. Best of luck.

Comment: The reference question contains examples, and there are more under [tag:algorithm-analysis+loops]. Closing your question because you don't say what you tried, specifically, and where you did get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, $j$ will take the values $1, 2, 4, 8, \dotsc, 2^k$ where $2^k<n$. You need to know how many times this will iterate. In other words, what will be the largest $k$ for which we have $2^k < n$? Take the log to the base 2 of each side of the inequality and you're asking what the largest $k$ will be for which $k<\log_2n$. What this means is that you're right in your comment: the loop will iterate no more than $\log_2n$ times.